# Purge a repository from my Github, using the command line

Tags: git, github

I clearly understand how to purge a Github repository from my account [using the web interface](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository)...

But I can't figure out how to perform the same operation from my local command line using a properly authenticated git client.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete remote branches in a Github repository (you cannot delete the project or repository itself, without using Github's special APIs). Push to the branch with a leading colon to delete it.

`git push <remote name> :<branch name>`

Typically, for a simple Github project, with one master branch, checked out using the command line example shown in a project page, this would be:

`git push origin :master`

Certainly, *be careful* with this destructive command. Check your remote and branch names if there are other remotes or branches in your project you really don't want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the GitHub API documentation for the "delete repository" call: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository

You need to authenticate using OAuth, not SSH or HTTP authentication, and then send a DELETE HTTP request to https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo.